# How to stay in while loop, but pausing to receive new button input

Tags: python

I'm new at programming and I cant seem to figure out how to make "konto" keep updating without it being in a while loop. Problem with the while loop is it doesn't allow new button input because it freezes the window.

I've tried making "konto" local, splitting the code into different functions, changing the loop style. Break exits the loop so "konto" doesn't update.

```
konto = 100
roulette_window = Tk()

def roulette(chosen_color, sats, konto):
    while True:
        x = randint(0, 36)
        if x == 0:
            green_num = x
            print(green_num, 'Green')
            color = ('Green')
            if color and chosen_color == 'Green':
                win_amount = 35 * int(sats)
        elif (x % 2) == 0:
            red_num = x
            print(red_num, 'Red')
            color = ('Red')
            if color and chosen_color == 'Red':
                win_amount = 2 * int(sats)
        elif (x % 2) == 1:
            black_num = x
            color = ('Black')
            print(black_num, 'Black')
            if color and chosen_color == 'Black':
                win_amount = 2 * int(sats)
        if not color == chosen_color:
            win_amount = 0
        konto = konto - int(sats) + int(win_amount)
        print(konto)

def bet_black():
    sats = bet_input.get(1.0, END)
    chosen_color = 'Black'
    bet_input.delete(1.0, END)
    roulette(chosen_color, sats, konto)


def bet_red():
```

I want to be able to call the function "roulette" once by eg. bet_black button click, and then click bet_red after one loop, while still having the updated "konto" variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly your variable `konto` is a global variable and you need to indicate to python that it is. Change your method to:

```py
def roulette(chosen_color, sats):
    global konto
    ...
```

Variables in Python have scoping rules which determine where they are valid. Anytime you assign to a variable a local version of the variable is created unless you have explicitly marked it as a global variable.

Secondly, I'm not sure why you have the `while True` structure here. This will cause an infinite loop unless you `break` out of it or `return`.

Comment: Thank you, it works now. I had tried the global command before, but i kept receiving an error message so i gave up. The while loop was the only way i could seem to make it update "konto", removing it now though.